# Add Identifier to json response

Tags: javascript, html, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a currency widget for my website and I'm using [this](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/) github based free Api which provides currencies in JSON format.

i want to display 4 different currencies, but my problem is that, when my json is parsing information from these  4 different URL's, every html element is just showing 1 currency number.

because json response doesnt have any identifier which i would use. Is there any way that i can assign identifiers manually or something like that? Thanks for help. Here is my full code.

```
    <div style="width: 175px;height: 72px;margin-top: -15px;">
<script>
var index = ["usd/gel.json", "eur/gel.json", "rub/gel.json", "gbp/gel.json"];
for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {

    var link = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/" + index[i];

    let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", link);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
             document.getElementById('valuta-usd').innerHTML = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText).gel;
     document.getElementById('valuta-eur').innerHTML = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText).gel;
     document.getElementById('valuta-rub').innerHTML = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText).gel;
     document.getElementById('valuta-gbp').innerHTML = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText).gel;
            
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send();
    
}    
</script>
<div id="valuta123">
<div style="display: inline-flex;">1 USD&nbsp;<img src="/templates/askinfov3/images/flags/usd.png" alt="USD" style="height: 16px;">&nbsp;=&nbsp;<div id="valuta-usd">იტვირთება</div></div>
<div style="display: inline-flex;">1 EUR &nbsp;<img src="/templates/askinfov3/images/flags/eur.png" alt="EUR" style="height: 16px;">&nbsp;=&nbsp;<div id="valuta-eur">იტვირთება</div></div>
<div style="display: inline-flex;">1 RUB &nbsp;<img src="/templates/askinfov3/images/flags/rub.png" alt="RUB" style="height: 16px;">&nbsp;=&nbsp;<div id="valuta-rub">იტვირთება</div></div>
<div style="display: inline-flex;">1 GBP &nbsp;<img src="/templates/askinfov3/images/flags/gbp.png" alt="GBP" style="height: 16px;">&nbsp;=&nbsp;<div id="valuta-gbp">იტვირთება</div></div>
</div>
 
    
    
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use another array `ids[]` to track which currency you are retrieving in each iteration.

```html
<div style="width: 175px;height: 72px;margin-top: -15px;">
    <div id="valuta123">
    <div style="display: inline-flex;">1 USD&nbsp;<img src="/templates/askinfov3/images/flags/usd.png" alt="USD" style="height: 16px;">&nbsp;=&nbsp;<div id="valuta-usd">იტვირთება</div></div>
    <div style="display: inline-flex;">1 EUR &nbsp;<img src="/templates/askinfov3/images/flags/eur.png" alt="EUR" style="height: 16px;">&nbsp;=&nbsp;<div id="valuta-eur">იტვირთება</div></div>
    <div style="display: inline-flex;">1 RUB &nbsp;<img src="/templates/askinfov3/images/flags/rub.png" alt="RUB" style="height: 16px;">&nbsp;=&nbsp;<div id="valuta-rub">იტვირთება</div></div>
    <div style="display: inline-flex;">1 GBP &nbsp;<img src="/templates/askinfov3/images/flags/gbp.png" alt="GBP" style="height: 16px;">&nbsp;=&nbsp;<div id="valuta-gbp">იტვირთება</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
    var index = ["usd/gel.json", "eur/gel.json", "rub/gel.json", "gbp/gel.json"];
    for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
    
        var link = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/" + index[i];
    
        let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", link);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
                var ids = ["valuta-usd", "valuta-eur", "valuta-rub", "valuta-gbp"];
                var data = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                document.getElementById(ids[i]).innerHTML = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText).gel;
                
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.send();
        
    }    
    </script>
```

Comment: (index):67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlHttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: @NomadTuner remove `.gel` property attached to JSON.parse(). See my update.

Comment: i did, it still throws that error in console i had .gel property attached because i only wanted to parse gel data in json response

Comment: @NomadTuner Try the changes, also put the script after the html, if possible just before the closing body tag

Comment: still not working, getting same error, i think json is not parsing anything from api, because console is not logging data :                 console.log(data);

Comment: @NomadTuner I've also reattached the.gel property, since you mentioned it's the property data you are interested in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243368/discussion-between-udo-e-and-nomad-tuner).